# Javascript array get one element by the other

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
listOf:[
  {name: "One", title: "Get Clown"},
  {name: "Two", title: "Find Bob"},
  {name: "Three", title: "Get Josh"}
]
```

How can I get one element by the other? For example, get the `title` "Find Bob" by looking for the `name` "Two".

Comment: You can use `Array#find`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listOf.find(element => element.name === 'Two').title
```